# like in exist() xml mssql

Tags: sql-server, xml, like

By following question: [See if XML element exists at any level in document with a specific value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152680/see-if-xml-element-exists-at-any-level-in-document-with-a-specific-value?newreg=65d7d2b86d7249e285d9f6bb6dc4d62f)

Is there a possible solution to implement `like` clause within `exist`?
For example I have similar structure of XML as in question but in "tag" :`<ContactLName>somevalues;Brandt;anothervalues</ContactLName>`
"Brandt" stored a little different. To find "Btandt" I have to use something like `like`, but I didn't find anything. 
Here is an example what I am looking for:
`WHERE  tmp.[XmlCol].exist(N'/*/ContactLName[text() like "%Brandt%"]') = 1;`

---

**Edit(XML):**

```
<event>
<id>23456</id>
<status_in_knowledge_map>active</status_in_knowledge_map>
<custom_elems>
    <custom_elem>
        <name>f_n84u</name>
        <value>6769747818850362088;6622044220776915827;5370802024842340642;6583457400600680603;6724970265512462551;6954452686001110038;6667448592984922570;6390613356250088198;6985638718331227440;5370802050233479119;5370802024842340639;6208275408034531857;6078654416541145539;6585528811993904287;6805915353243667957;6842010739999728536;6964839747571514100;6491764192266708067;6630060828301937234;6964682936739957053;6996382008379854236;5703859111941721724;6780468964682252783;</value>
    </custom_elem>
    <custom_elem>
        <name>f_twxr</name>
        <value>7031439420534698908;5667697629116916565;5667697629116916521;7032219545122506576;7032219609944822365;7032219012824308287;7032219395780000352</value>
    </custom_elem>
</custom_elems>
<asd>adsf</asd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fn:contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/functions-on-string-values-contains?view=sql-server-ver15) in the predicate.

```
c.data.exist('/course/custom_elems/text()[fn:contains(., "7032219868543590434")]') = 1;
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but unfortinatelly it shows an empty result. With the `.value` method it works. Maybe exact XML structure will give a little help to visualize the problem, I will edit my question and add the sctructure.

Comment: @Fatdrfrog Looks like it is working for me. Have a look here. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8df33c0a3c2965bd6a7a655bc354dc2 Of course I had to change your XML a bit and use a value that is actually in there and adapt the XQuery to the new structure.

Comment: yap, it works. I've tried `exist` by finding `node()` and it worked perfect. I even combined `value` and `contains` by node():
SELECT e.data.value('(/event/custom_elems/node()[fn:contains(., "f_n84u")])[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') as df;
and it found needed value.

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer by using `value()`:

```sql
WHERE c.data.value('(/course/custom_elems)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') LIKE '%7032219868543590434%'
```

Question is probably a dublicate and has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832987/use-a-like-statement-on-sql-server-xml-datatype).